# Why is my function returning the object identity instead of the 'ip' variable?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

**Upon saving User sign up form, I expect to save an ip address of the user, but my view function won't return a string**.
I get the object identity of the get_client_signup_ip function instead:

```py
<function get_client_signup_ip at 0x04461810>
```

**forms.py:**

```py
    from django import forms
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from django.http import HttpRequest

from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2

from . import views

from .models import CustomUser

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser # this makes the UserCreateForm always save data to the custom user model
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")


    def save(self, commit=True, request=True): # user object (customuser) form is called to save with commit=true, so it gets teh ip and saves.
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.origin_ip = views.get_client_signup_ip(request)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```py
def get_client_signup_ip(request):
    g = GeoIP2()
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for
        ip2 = '192.227.139.106'
        city = g.city(ip2)
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        ip2 = '192.227.139.106'
        city = g.city(ip2)

    return ip
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('signup/', views.get_client_ip, name='signup_ipaddress')

]
```

I expect to see an ip address in the User's origin_ip field. Instead I get an string representation for the get_client_sign_up function.

How can I get my view function get_client_sign_ip to return a string?

Comment: that is the default string representation of a python object. You are not getting "the object identity" However, that is the representation of the *function object*, you perhaps meant to call it, i.e. `views.get_client_ip()` instead of simply `views.get_client_ip`, but I am not familiar with django

Comment: update your complete forms.py here.

Comment: @AstikAnand I have updated it

Comment: check if request object is available inside your method.

Comment: It is. I believe the problem is that I do not have request defined in forms.py. But I do not know how to create a request object in my forms class correctly. In this case here with ```request=True```, I get bool type has no attribute META, which is coming from the views.py method.

Comment: I don't know why you have also put `get_client_ip` in the urls. Since it has the same path as Signup, it will never be called. But you don't need it to be called from there anyway. You should remove that line.

Comment: I have get_client_signup_ip in urls.py currently with the same path as signup because it is a function that runs with on the sign up page.

Howver, my current issue seems to be that I cannot access request object in forms.py which makes results in me not being able to call my views function get_client_signup_ip in views.py. get_client_signup_ip(request) says that request argument is NoneType.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value you need to call it as method **`views.get_client_signup_ip()`** instead of `views.get_client_signup_ip`.

```
user.origin_ip = views.get_client_signup_ip(request)
```

Also, for simply getting ip from a function you don't need the `HttpResponse(ip)` from a method.

```
def get_client_signup_ip(request):
    ..........

    return ip
```

Comment: Thank you this is closer to what I need. However, I realized I cannot call get_client_signup_ip() without passing a request argument.

I am unable to do so in forms.py. Do you know how I can get this to work?

I will update my code

Comment: Yeah that's one more thing, you need to call with request parameter. I will edit the aanswer.

Comment: I am unsure how to do so within the forms.py when not in my views.py

Comment: ```user.origin_ip =views.get_client_signup_ip()```

Requires a parameter, request. You can see this in my views.py.

```def get_client_signup_ip(request):```

Comment: This is what I get

```get_client_signup_ip() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'```

Comment: Pass it with request parameter, request parameter will be available in forms also.

Comment: I get this when I do:

```'NoneType' object has no attribute 'META'```